# How do you configure resque-web to use Resque.redis.namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, resque

I have set the Resque.redis.namespace for my application and now resque-web not longer displays the workers and queues.

Is there some way to get resque-web to be aware of the redis.namespace or ideally multiple redis namspaces?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assume that you set Resque.redis.namespace in `config/initializers/resque.rb`. Than you can run resque-web passing path to this file as command line argument, e.g.:

```
resque-web -p 8282 rails_root/config/initializers/resque.rb
```

Also you can pass namespace directly through command line option `-N` like so:

```
resque-web -p 8282 -N myapp
```