# How do you start resque to use Resque.redis.namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

Using resque, I would like to specify a namespace and be able to see the workers in resque-web

The resque rake task is started this way:

```
COUNT=5 QUEUE=* RESQUE_NAMESPACE="resque:myapp" rake environment resque:workers
```

namespace is specified in config/initializers/resque.rb

```
Resque.redis.namespace = "resque:myapp"
```

Resque-web show on the UI the correct namespace but 0 workers are visible.

If I don't specify any namespace, everything is working ok.

A very similar question has been asked.
[How do you configure resque-web to use Resque.redis.namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363864/how-do-you-configure-resque-web-to-use-resque-redis-namespace?answertab=active#tab-top), but it doesn't answer my question.

Any, clue or help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set `RESQUE_NAMESPACE` when loading your Resque worker, since it will load your Rails app with the `Resque.redis.namespace` directive.

When starting `resque-web`, you should use the `-N` param:

```
  resque-web -N myapp
```

And it should work just fine.

P.S.: I am not confident about the colon on the namespace, try not using it.

Comment: In testing this, it appears that the namespace has to be just `"myapp"` in `config/initializers/resque.rb` to match `-N myapp` for resque-web. resque will add the ':resque:' to it's keys after the namespace.

Comment: This worked for me too. I set my resque initializer like this
`Resque.redis.namespace = :ts`
And started my resque-web like jmonteiro & jwadsack suggested with `-N ts`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're setting this after you set your `redis`

```
ENV["OPENREDIS_URL"] ||= "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
uri = URI.parse(ENV["OPENREDIS_URL"])

Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
Rails.logger.info('Connected to Redis')
RESQUE_NAMESPACE = :my_namespace
Resque.redis.namespace = RESQUE_NAMESPACE
```

If you try to set `Resque.redis.namespace =` before `Resque.redis =` it gets over-written.

Also make sure to set this in any after_fork callbacks for your webserver (unicorn/puma/etc):

```
on_worker_boot do
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
    Rails.logger.info('Connected to ActiveRecord')
  end

  if defined?(Resque)
    ENV["OPENREDIS_URL"] ||= "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
    uri = URI.parse(ENV["OPENREDIS_URL"])
    Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
    Resque.redis.namespace = RESQUE_NAMESPACE
    Rails.logger.info('Connected to Redis')
  end
end
```