# Ignoring unregister_worker in resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, procfile

My rails app consists of an **API server** and an **Admin server**. Both make use of resque jobs.

In my local development environment each of them have a Procfile and are using the same redis server. The problem I have is that I cannot control which server is picking up which job. Each server has distinct queues, but they seem to be picked up in the 'unregister_worker' routine.

```
/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/resque-1.24.1/lib/resque/worker.rb:459:in `unregister_worker'
```

I see this in my call stack and it leads to a ruby error since it doesn't know the class.

How can I tell resque to ignore an `unregister_worker'? Just to clarify I don't have a worker task associated with the '*' queue.

As a workaround I could run two redis servers locally as I do in my production environment, but I like to avoid that if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Redis Namespaces do exactly that. In 'config/initializers/resque.rb' specify the namespace of the queue:

```
Resque.redis.namespace = "resque:admin_server"
```

Found the solution here:
[How do you start resque to use Resque.redis.namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236593/how-do-you-start-resque-to-use-resque-redis-namespace)